# Resetting Certificates Using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, certificate, app-store

Will I be able to upload an update of the exiting app if I choose to reset the distribution certificate through Xcode. Can I assume that reseting the certificate will not restrict me from updating an existing app.

Thanks in advance. need help.please share your views.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem doing this.You can reset certificate through Xcode.If you reset certificate then Xcode will revokes and re-creates the corresponding certificate.